# Team Foundation Service Automated Build and Test Database Error

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to setup automated builds and tests on Team Foundation Service, and I can't get the tests to connect to my Azure database, so my tests keep failing.

The build goes just fine, but any test that causes the site to connect to my database fails. I setup my database on Azure and associated it with my Azure site. I configured the allowed IP addresses for the database to include my local machine and set it to allow Azure services to connect. The site works locally on my machine, and also when published to my Azure website, and connects to the Azure database from both places just fine.

I am using Team Foundation Service (https://tfs.visualstudio.com/) for my source control, and have setup automated builds in Team Foundation Service and continuous deployment to Azure from those builds. All other aspects of that work fine, source control, builds starting on checkin, builds deploying to my Azure site, but none of my tests are passing.

*Error Messages:*

On a project with code first EF:

> Test method MySite.Tests.Controllers.HomeControllerTest.Index threw
>   exception:  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: CREATE DATABASE
>   permission denied in database 'master'.

On a project with database first EF:

> Test method tfstest4.Tests.Controllers.HomeControllerTest.Index threw
>   exception:  System.InvalidOperationException: No connection string
>   named 'TestDbContext' could be found in the application config file.

(note that the connection string does exist, and that it works just fine locally and after it's deployed to Azure)

Any advice on running unit tests on Team Foundation Service where database access is required is much appreciated.

Comment: And the connection string for local (web.config/web.debug.config) points to a local db (SQL Express/ (local)) or to Azure DB?

Comment: Have you checked you app.config file in the test project to verify the connectionstring are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running automated *unit tests*, my advice is to remove any dependencies to your database, as there is no reason for you to test Entity Framework. What I would personally do is to hide my database layer behind some form of repository interface, and offer some mock implementations when running my tests, using some form of dependency injection strategy or factory pattern.

If you are also running automated *integration tests* it might make more sense to involve the database. It might appear that your connection string is not present in the test project's configuration. I am not sure how you tell EF which connection string to use, but I suggest avoiding a direct dependency to a settings entry.

If you use EF Code First you can supply the connection string as an argument to the base constructor of your DbContext class. You could for example put your connection string into a static property, and fetch it when instantiating your db context

```
public static class MyConnectionStringProvider
{
    public static string ConnectionString{ get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() 
       : base(MyConnectionStringProvider.ConnectionString)
    { }
}
```

Now, at some point in your app startup and test set up routines you can set the connection string. This allows you to control which connection string to use.

For example, if you are running an azure web site you would typically get your connection string from the role configuration rather than an app.config file, in your Application_Start method.

```
MyConnectionStringProvider.ConnectionString = 
     RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("MyConnectionString")
```

In your test class, you could do something entirely different

```
MyConnectionStringProvider.ConnectionString = "[connectionstring to my test database]"
```

Finally, there might be some firewall quirks that needs to be sorted out, since you might need to add an exception in the SQL Azure servers firewall for the computer running the test. I'd contact MS Support about this if it turns out to be necessary.

Comment: The important part for fixing the immediate technical problem was noting that the connection string was not present in my test project. I had been testing locally and didn't realize the test project had a separate app.config file. Copying my connection string from app.config to web.config made the test run in in my Team Foundation Service build. 

The general advice to remove database dependencies from my tests is also good and I will work on that as well.